# Jslider - How to I extract min and max range?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jslider

I've managed to get egorkhmelev's jslider http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/ displaying properly, but I'm a bit of a noob, and am unsure how to extract both min and max values from the range, so that I can use it in a query.

```
<div class="layout-slider">
    <input id="Slider2" name="PricePar" value="5000;50000" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery("#Slider2").slider({

    from: 5000,
    to: 150000,
    heterogeneity: ['50/50000'],
    step: 1000, dimension: '&nbsp;$',
});
```

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/HKhBH/

I'm using this in an asp.net MVC solution with C#, if that helps any.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

from my experience with the plugin, it places the min and max values in the textbox. Once you pass the values back to the controller, you're responsible for string splitting the values on the `;`